# Disconnect Strophe Connection on Page Unload

Tags: jquery, xmpp, strophe

I've written a web-based MUC client using strophe.js and jQuery and I'm trying to send an 
unavailable presence to the room and disconnect the user in the jquery 
unload event for the window.  If a user navigates away or closes the 
browser tab, they should be logged out of the MUC.

I've tested the code that I'm running in this event through a logout 
button I have on the page, so I'm pretty sure the stanza is correct. 
I think strophe is having trouble sending the stanza if the browser 
window is closing.  Is there any workaround here?  I've also tried the 
onbeforeunload event (I know it's not entirely cross-browser 
compatible), but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Thanks, 
John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure you switch to sync mode, and call `flush()` before sending your `disconnect()` call. Here is an example:

```
var Client = {
  connect: function(spec) {
    this.connection = new Strophe.Connection(spec.url);
  },

  disconnect: function() {
    this.connection.options.sync = true; // Switch to using synchronous requests since this is typically called onUnload.
    this.connection.flush();
    this.connection.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Then you can bind to onbeforeunload/onunload. (jQuery example)

```
var client = new Client;
client.connect();
$(window).unload(function() {
  client.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: You will need a patched Strophe.js: https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/issues/16

Comment: For the latest strophe you must use this.connection.options.sync = true;

Comment: connection.options.sync = true actually made my hybrid app freeze while relogin. Seriously. I did a small chrome profiling . It showed that when you relogin after logout,the entire app freezed. However, when I removed sync = true, everything was fine. What exactly does this sync does?. I am assuming that it sets a sync pattern after which every operation is synhronous. The default being asynchronous, solved my problem. I am still not able to get my head around it

Answer (score 2):

No patches needed, there's now a built-in solution:

```
connection.flush();
connection._options.sync = true;    
connection.disconnect();
```